# Why are not reproducible/typo flags listed under "needs improvement"?

Tags: support, bug, flags, close-reasons

When you flag a question that was caused by a simple typo mistake, the option is listed under "needs improvement" which says:

> This question needs updates from the author in order to be answered well or belongs on another Stack Exchange site.

However, typo mistakes which are the root cause of an entire question cannot be edited to improve said question, and the only course of action is to either close or delete it.

So, why is the option for "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" listed under the "needs improvement" section? Shouldn't it simply be in the initial prompt window as its own category?

And while we're at it, roasting the flagging prompt:

1. Why is duplicate listed on the initial flag prompt and also in the needs improvement section?
2. Why does clicking the duplicate option on the initial prompt and then clicking the back button take you to the needs improvement section? Back implies it will take you to the previous menu you were at.
3. Why do the initial flag prompt's options start in lower case and the needs improvement options start in upper case?

Comment: Related post on Meta Stack Exchange: [Why are the "off-topic" flag options (including "blatantly off-topic") listed under "needs improvement"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351279/348196)

Comment: Almost positive I answered something like this a long while ago - need to find it.  But in summary, it is just how the dialogs are set up.  Duplicates get special attention in the Flag dialog so they get listed separately.  But when you click on "Needs Improvement", the dialog you see is actually the close dialog (same thing that 3K users see when they click the "Close" button.  SO obviously didn't feel it was necessary to design a special close flag dialog that removes the duplicated "duplicate" flag

Comment: How would you improve a question when the root cause of the error/malfunction/unexpected behavior/result is a typo?

Comment: flagging is one of, if not the most intimidating actions you can take on this site. and as you've pointed out, these ambiguous descriptions provide negative explanation