# How can we improve the wording & navigation to the "not reproducible / caused by typo" flag reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, user-experience, flag-dialog

As a reminder, we close no-longer-reproducible/caused-by-typo questions because:

> While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

Here's where confusion arises for me:

##### Flag dialog "needs improvement"

In the flag dialog, this flag reason shows up under "needs improvement". But it's not intuitive to me how something that was already resolved in a way that is not likely to be helpful to future readers due to being no-longer-reproducible/caused-by-typo can be improved in a way that makes it more likely to be helpful to future readers.

If something is no longer reproducible, what can you do? Make the problem reproducible again? Should I go cause an eternal world power outage (would I get in trouble for that?)? Jokes aside, I could understand if the improvement would be to make it very clear in the question post the conditions that make the problem difficult to reproduce / are out of the control of the average asker of the question.

If the problem is due to a typo, how can it be improved to make it more helpful to future readers? Even if you make it into an MRE of a typo, it's still an MRE of a typo. To be fair, I *have* seen such a question being very useful to others (a PHP one about someone coming from JS using the wrong operator for string concatenation), but I think that's the exception rather than the norm (data needed to support this claim).

As I explained above, I have guesses as to how such questions could actually be improved. Are they correct? Regardless of what the explanation/guidance is, why isn't it included in [the Help Center page on closure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), or in the MarkdownPostOwnerGuidance or MarkdownPublicGuidance for this close reason? I think if I were a new asker and got a post closed for this reason, I'd have no idea what to do next except nothing. It would be nice to link them to [our FAQ post on the subject](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417482/11107541).

##### Triage Queue: Flag

The description of the "Flag" action in the Triage queue says "*This post cannot be answered.*", which just seems to be totally contradictory to "*[...] this one was resolved in a way [...]*".

##### Discussion

Do other people find this confusing? If so, do you have ideas on how the UI could be improved to resolve the confusion?

If we have some consensus on what the problem is and a solution we like, we can write up a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Note: I'm aware that the more underlying a feature-request asks for, the less likely it will / longer it could take to get put in [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), but I'd rather have us voice ourselves than to not.

Comment: Yes, this is confusing and has been since the last flag/close dialog revamp (IIRC, in part, changing "should be closed..." to "needs improvement"). I'd suggest looking at the various proposals which have been put forth since then both here on MSO and on MSE. So far, SE has chosen not to implement anything.

Comment: Your Title is (also) not very clear, ... and your Post is full of Typos... (=> annoying). // But yep-yep, the whole UI Navigation for the `Flag` Functionality (on a Question) is completely buggy and contra-intuitive, typically done by a "*Stagiaire*" who never used 'SO' before..., (took me years to realize there was a next Screen after `Needs improvement`, ah-ah...!), with `Duplicate` x2, `Spam` and `Abusive` should be together behind a `Report ...` 1st Option, `Blatantly off-topic` (same like `Caused by a typo`) is 2nd Level behind `Needs improvement` (=> what kind of improvements...!?).

Comment: Duplicate? [Why are not reproducible/typo flags listed under "needs improvement"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415632/6083675) Also there's a link to [specialized guidance for all the close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/6083675) in that Help Center article.

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for the link. I haven't seen that. But I also include discussion on the triage queue.

Comment: Yep, good, Thanks for correcting the "annoying" Typos ("improvement" + "concatenation"), the last "to" in "*than to not.*" could be omitted, grammatically correct is "than not.", or maybe "than not to." (I think...). And "condolences" are for when sbd died, nbd's dead (yet!)...! // "*... do you have ideas on how the UI could be improved to resolve the confusion?*" => Yep, but then ask a Qt about "How can the UI Navigation for the `flag` Func on Qt's can be improved?", => not only about 1 of the 14 Items in that "Box", but about all of them and the whole Navigation...

Comment: For the Flag option in the Triage queue, maybe change "cannot be answered" to "cannot or should not be answered". Almost all questions that *should* be closed *can* be answered, except maybe questions that need details or clarity.